# Specificaly silent Pandas SettingWithCopyWarning using warnings context manager?

Tags: python, pandas, warnings

I have the policy of showing all warnings:

```
import warnings
warnings.simplefilter('always')
```

I would like to silent some false positive Pandas warnings using context managers:

```
with warnings.catch_warnings():
    warnings.filterwarnings('ignore', category=SettingWithCopyWarning)
    # Some assignment raising false positive warning that should be silenced

# Some assignment actually raising a true positive warning
```

But after having a look on [Pandas source](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/tree/master/pandas), I cannot found where the object `SettingWithCopyWarning` is defined in Pandas.

Does anyone know where this object is defined in Pandas namespace?

Comment: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/ff1fa4e55c90bb1ec3dc03987f989791eabda7d8/pandas/core/common.py#L28-#L29

Comment: @coldspeed Thank you for pointing it out, I missed it I was looking in `errors.py`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Merging information from comments into a single answer:

```
import warnings
import pandas as pd
```

As @Andrew pointed out, I can achieve it using dedicated Pandas Context Manager:

```
with pd.option_context('mode.chained_assignment', None):
    # Chaining Assignment, etc...
```

Or using the PSL `warnings` provided I can locate the warning `SettingWithCopyWarning` object (thanks to @coldspeed for the GitHub link):

```
with warnings.catch_warnings():
    warnings.filterwarnings('ignore', category=pd.core.common.SettingWithCopyWarning)
    # Chaining Assignment, etc...
```

Notice both solution seems to behave similarly but they are not exactly equivalent:

- Pandas Context Manager temporarily alters Pandas options an then restores it;
- [PSL Context Manager](https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html#temporarily-suppressing-warnings) catches a specific warning and silent it without altering Pandas options.

**Additional information**

It can be worthy to convert this specific warning into error:

```
pd.set_option('mode.chained_assignment', 'raise')
```

This will force your development to avoid those specific edge-cases and force your code to explicitly state if it works on view or only on a copy.

Off course the exception can be caught as usual:

```
try:
    # Chaining Assignment, etc...
except pd.core.common.SettingWithCopyError:
    pass
```

But in this case, converting warning into error will likely force you to modify the ambiguous code until the error vanishes instead of catching the related exception.

**Observation**

IMHO, completely silent those warnings using:

```
pd.set_option('mode.chained_assignment', None)
```

Is a bad practice, and does not help to produce better code.

Comment: I believe these have moved to `pd.errors`

Answer (score 2):

The following should do what you are looking for:

`pd.set_option('mode.chained_assignment', None)`

taken from https://www.dataquest.io/blog/settingwithcopywarning/

However, take some time to read the above article as it explains much about that warning. Perhaps you do not want to always silence it!

Comment: No I want to specifically silent it, this is why I use a context manager. I already know about this. Thank you for answering anyway.

Comment: `with pd.option_context('mode.chained_assignment', None):`

Comment: from the linked article

Comment: Thank you for the link and pointing out the context manager. I have merged both comments from you and @coldspeed into an answer. I think this how it suits best to the OP.